# Using list.files(pattern = ???) to only list files with characters from a-z and 0-9, ignore files with special characters

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to generate a list of paths using `list.files()` and I am using the following:

```
paths <- list.files(path = params$path[[1]], 
                    pattern = '*', 
                    all.files = TRUE, 
                    full.names = TRUE, 
                    recursive = TRUE, 
                    ignore.case = TRUE)
```

However, I have filenames with special characters (accents, question marks.. ect). These cause my issue down the road. For now, I want to ignore those files from this list. I am trying to do this with the pattern= param but not having any luck.

Been trying the following as a start but now I cannot find any files..

```
paths <- list.files(path = params$path[[1]], 
                           pattern='(a-z)', 
                           all.files=TRUE, 
                           full.names=TRUE, 
                           recursive=TRUE, 
                           ignore.case=TRUE)
```

Can anyone suggest a regex that I could add into the pattern param to find file names which only contain [a-z] and/or [0-9] but not anything else, no special chars?

Comment: Try `pattern = "^[[:alpha:]]+$"`  If the files are all `.csv`, then `"^[[:alpha:]]+\\.csv$"`

Comment: Specific to your provided example, to match "a-z", the pattern would be `[a-z]` in brackets, not parenthesis. You can match a-z, and 0-9 with `^[A-z0-9]+$`

Comment: Still not finding anything using either of these two suggestions meanwhile ```pattern='*' ``` finds all of the files. Is it because paths contain slashes? Does pattern only look at the file name or the total path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include letters or numbers only, you also need to account for the extension in some way.  The pattern in the command below starts with one or more letters and/or numbers and then ends with a period and 3 or 4 letters and/or numbers.

```
paths <- list.files( path=params$path[[1]], pattern='^[a-z0-9]+?\\.[a-z0-9]{3,4}$', all.files=TRUE, full.names=FALSE, recursive=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE )
```

Comment: Thank you Kerry, and everyone for that matter. Kerry, one small follow up. If I did want to include a white space " " and or a "-" along with the [a-z0-9] how would I add those? You can see I'm new to regex :)

Comment: Figured it out :).. ```pattern='^[a-z0-9 -]+?\\.[a-z0-9]{3,4}$'``` Thanks everyone.